# Mapping from one plane on the other plane despite of masking regions

Tags: python, coordinate-system, spherical-geometry, gdalwarp, orthorectification

have a set of data given [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3HWMYm2lTkVVEFaeTd6VGY5VDA/edit), where in the first and second columns there are the sky coordinates (ra,dec) e.g. right ascension and declination, respectively and in the third and forth, the coordinates in a Cartesian system (x,y), e.g. positions on the CCD image. [image]

I need to make a two-dimensional interpolation surface using coordinates x and y and another using Ra and Dec. The problem is the existence of masked regions, as shown in the figure above. That is what I so far tried and didn't give the right answer:

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('test.asc')

ra = data[:,0]
dec = data[:,1]
Xpos = data[:,2]
Ypos = data[:,3]

xi = np.linspace(Xpos.min(), Xpos.max(), 1000)
yi = np.linspace(Ypos.min(), Ypos.max(), 1000)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi, copy=False)
ra_int = griddata(data[:,2:4], ra, (xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()),
                  method='cubic')
dec_int = griddata(data[:,2:4], dec, (xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()),
                   method='cubic')
```

Using griddata fails and return just `NaN` values. Is there any way to do this interpolation in order to estimate the values of Ra and Dec from a given x and y coordinates even in the masked regions (map from `x` and `y` to `ra` and `dec`)?

Comment: What exactly are you interpolating? Each image appears only to have constant values (as indicated by the constant colors), leaving nothing to interpolate.  Perhaps if we could better understand what you mean by a "two-dimensional interpolation surface" that might clear things up.

Comment: @whuber I want to find a mapping from `x` and `y` coordinate to the `ra` and `dec` coordinate. In order to do that I think I need to find an interpolation in the `x` and `y` coordinate in order to obtain values for the missing regions and the same for `ra` and `dec` and then estimate the mapping.

Comment: There are many ways to do this: your problem essentially is identical to changing coordinate systems in a map. However, I would guess that (ra, dec) are right ascension and declination and that (x,y) may be related to them via a transformation from spherical coordinates followed (perhaps?) by a linear transformation. In this case you shouldn't have to estimate the transformation; you could just write down the formula and apply it. What, then, do you know about the (x,y) coordinates and their relationship to (ra, dec)?

Comment: @whuber you are right they are right ascension and declination and x and y, positions of each object on the CCD. I don't know how I could find an analytical function that does the transformation.

Comment: Aha! It's a sensor. Although with an ideal imaging system the transformation can be determined mathematically, there may be various aberrations that cause slight deflections from the mathematical solution. Ideally you would use multiple images--including those that were not masked--to calibrate the transformation. Do such images exist? If not, you can indeed treat this as a GIS-like image "warping" or rectification problem (for which you have an abundance of data). Because you have revealed important information in these comments, please edit the question to include it.

Comment: @whuber I updated the information. Imagining that these images don't exist could you please elaborate more **a GIS-like image "warping" or rectification problem**?

Comment: Reviewing [the threads on our site where "rectification" is mentioned](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=rectification) might clarify it.  (There are likely many more threads under "warping" but they will be hard to distinguish from those complaining that some map or image got "warped.")

Comment: @whuber I was wondering whether it shouldn't be a common mapping problem from a flat plane to a spherical or sky coordinate or not?

Comment: Yes: that's a gnomonic projection (followed by a projective transformation depending on the position of the sensor plane relative to the axis of the lens). But you would need to check first that the imaging system does not incorporate substantial distortions relative to that projection.

Comment: @whuber one question that I asked in stackoverflow and didn't get any appropriate answer was related to [`inverse gnomonic projection`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343266/inverse-gnomonic-projections-of-plane).